# Get count of rows based on criteria - date field in specific year, grouped by text field

Tags: r, statistics

I have a excel report published daily which I need to summarize and provide the trend analysis. This report has list of work items with created date, work item type. How can I get count of work items created in 2011, 2012? Also, how do I get counts by work item type? So far I've been able to load the excel data and get number of rows by doing following -

```
library(gdata)
wi20121812 = read.xls("WorkItemReport20121812.xls")
nrow(wi20121812)
```

Sample Data

```
   > dput(head(workItemReport2))
structure(list(DocType = structure(c(6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("TYPE10WI", 
"TYPE11WI", "TYPE12WI", "TYPE13WI", "TYPE14WI", "TYPE1WI", "TYPE2WI", 
"TYPE3WI", "TYPE4WI", "TYPE5WI", "TYPE6WI", "TYPE7WI", "TYPE8WI", 
"TYPE9WI"), class = "factor"), CreatedDate = structure(c(7L, 
22L, 146L, 181L, 153L, 191L), .Label = c("1/10/12 15:43 AM/PM ", 
"1/10/12 16:06 AM/PM ", "1/10/12 5:28 AM/PM ", "1/10/12 5:56 AM/PM ", 
"1/11/12 19:51 AM/PM ", "1/11/12 5:26 AM/PM ", "1/12/11 21:58 AM/PM ", 
"1/12/12 11:08 AM/PM ", "1/12/12 5:41 AM/PM ", "1/12/12 9:56 AM/PM ", 
"1/13/12 14:01 AM/PM ", "1/13/12 15:08 AM/PM ", "1/13/12 15:11 AM/PM ", 
"1/13/12 8:51 AM/PM ", "1/16/12 10:27 AM/PM ", "1/16/12 10:28 AM/PM ", 
"1/16/12 16:37 AM/PM ", "1/16/12 7:52 AM/PM ", "1/18/12 15:02 AM/PM ", 
"1/18/12 16:03 AM/PM ", "1/18/12 16:13 AM/PM ", "1/19/11 19:23 AM/PM ", 
"1/20/12 10:48 AM/PM ", "1/20/12 12:23 AM/PM ", "1/20/12 8:38 AM/PM ", 
"1/23/12 5:53 AM/PM ", "1/24/12 15:18 AM/PM ", "1/24/12 8:23 AM/PM ", 
"1/24/12 8:58 AM/PM ", "1/25/12 11:38 AM/PM ", "1/25/12 5:28 AM/PM ", 
"1/26/12 13:48 AM/PM ", "1/26/12 15:53 AM/PM ", "1/26/12 15:58 AM/PM ", 
"1/26/12 16:13 AM/PM ", "1/26/12 16:18 AM/PM ", "1/26/12 7:33 AM/PM ", 
"1/27/12 7:48 AM/PM ", "1/3/12 17:48 AM/PM ", "1/3/12 18:33 AM/PM ", 
"1/3/12 9:07 AM/PM ", "1/30/12 11:22 AM/PM ", "1/30/12 22:52 AM/PM ", 
"1/30/12 23:10 AM/PM ", "1/31/12 19:54 AM/PM ", "1/31/12 20:39 AM/PM ", 
"1/31/12 5:42 AM/PM ", "1/31/12 9:42 AM/PM ", "1/4/12 14:02 AM/PM ", 
"1/4/12 9:52 AM/PM ", "1/5/12 13:42 AM/PM ", "1/5/12 17:42 AM/PM ", 
....
....
"9/6/12 9:02 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 11:48 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 12:58 AM/PM ", 
"9/7/12 13:52 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 15:07 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 15:12 AM/PM ", 
"9/7/12 15:22 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 15:47 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 15:52 AM/PM ", 
"9/7/12 8:42 AM/PM ", "9/7/12 9:32 AM/PM ", "9/8/11 23:43 AM/PM "
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DocType", "CreatedDate"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible data, e.g., `head(wi20121812)`.

Comment: Better yet: `dput(head(wi20121812))`

Comment: Added sample data to the question

Comment: @VineetBhatia Use the `dput` expression to produce this sample data.  It is unclear how the data look from your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one part of your question that remains unanswered, "how to get counts of work item types" is quite easy.

```
res <- table(wi20121812[, "WorkItemType"])
```

This will give you a simple table that tells you how often each WorkItemType occurred. If you need to have it in proportions, rather than absolute counts, run prop.table() on the result:

```
prop.table(res)
```

Or do it both at once:

```
res <- prop.table(table(wi20121812[, "WorkItemType"]))
```

Comment: Doing that I get > res <- table(workItemReport2[, "DocType"])
> prop.table(res)

   TYPE10WI    TYPE11WI    TYPE12WI    TYPE13WI    TYPE14WI     TYPE1WI     TYPE2WI     TYPE3WI     TYPE4WI     TYPE5WI 
0.005835544 0.010079576 0.030238727 0.001061008 0.001591512 0.303978780 0.013262599 0.036074271 0.384084881 0.107692308 
    TYPE6WI     TYPE7WI     TYPE8WI     TYPE9WI 
0.041909814 0.005835544 0.013262599 0.045092838 
>

Comment: Right. As these numbers are proportions, you'd just need to multiply them with 100 to get to percent. So Type10WI accounts for 0.6 percent of all work items, Type11WI about 1 percent, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
res = ddply(df, "year", summarise, amount = length(year))
```

or use `count` form the same package (which is even easier):

```
res = count(df, "year")
```

where `df` is a `data.frame` containing your data, and `year` is the column name of the column  which contains the categorical variable detailing in which year that row was created.

Comment: Doing count(workItemReport2, "CreatedDate") I get
> res
           CreatedDate freq
1              00:05.4    1
2              00:05.6    1
3              00:19.7    1
4              00:36.8    1
5              00:37.0    1
6              00:42.7    1
7              00:42.8    1 I want to get the count of work items created in the year 2011 and those created in the year 2012?